# How to understand syntax of this TypeScript/ES6 function?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm working through a tutorial on TypeScript/ES6.

The following code works e.g. outputs `["Richard Francis Burton"]`:

```
let convertToStringArray: (v: string) => string[] = (value) => [value];

let name = "Richard Francis Burton";
let names = convertToStringArray(name);
console.log(names);
```

But how does one understand the TypeScript/ES6 syntax?

- `convertToStringArray` is the function name with a parameter name `v` which has to be of type `string`
- this function returns `string[] = (value) => [value];`

But this would be the same as the following function which doesn't work (`Error TS1011: An element access expression should take an argument.`)

```
function convertToStringArray(v: string) {
    return string[] = (value) => [value];
}
```

Comment: Not a TS expert, but I believe the `(v: string) => string[]` is the type (so a function which accepts a string, and returns an array of strings), whereas `(value) => [value]` is the function which is being assigned (which conforms to the type specified).

Comment: Isn't the `string[]` the return type? You can't return that, have you tried removing the `string[]` after the return statement? You can put that after the parameter definitions for the function `convertToStringArray(v: string): string[] {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> this function returns `string[] = (value) => [value];`

No, the function returns `string[]` and the variable is initialized to `(value) => [value];`

```
         declaration           TypeScript type         (initial) value
/                      \  /                     \   /                \
let convertToStringArray: (v: string) => string[] = (value) => [value];
```

Comment: So that is the same as `let convertToStringArray = (value: string): string[] => [value];`, right?

Comment: Correct. Or just `let convertToStringArray = (value: string) => [value];`

Answer (score 1):

You've confused the inline type annotation with the function itself. What that says is you've got a variable `convertStringToArray` that has type `(v: string) => string[]` and is assigned `(value) => [value]`. It's equivalent to:

```
function convertToStringArray(value: string): string[] {
    return [value];
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBBA3ApgJygFTgZSkxjAHMBBTTAQwE8AKVagGxHQC5EBnIk0gSk49iZANoBdRAG8AUInmJM6KCExJRTVunEBuGQF8ZQA)